# Creating a contact list app(mean stack) not able to render data

Tags: angular, mongodb, postman, crud, mean-stack

Im trying to do a contact list app using mean stack to display contacts, add and delete them.
Im not able to render the contacts through ngfor from the component.ts and service.ts files.
Ive checked the working of the api to post and get in **postman** and it works fine there, but when it comes to component.html rendering the existing contacts from db is not happening and similary adding a new contact isnt working.
`contact.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="page-header">ADD NEW CONTACTS </h2>
    <form submit="addContact()" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>First name </label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "fname" name ="fname" class = "form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Last name </label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "lname" name ="lname" class = "form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Phone number: </label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "phno" name ="phno" class = "form-control" required>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add contact" >
    </form>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
    <div *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            {{contact.fname}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            {{contact.lname}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            {{contact.phno}}
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="button" (click) = "deleteContact(contact._id)" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

`

`contact.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactService } from '../contact.service';
import { Contact } from '../contact';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css'],
  providers: [ContactService]
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
  contacts!: Contact[];
  contact!: Contact;
  fname!: string;
  lname!:string;
  phno!:string;

  constructor(private contactService: ContactService) { }
  
  addContact()
  {
     const newContact = {
      fname: this.fname,
      lname: this.lname,
      phno: this.phno
     } 
     this.contactService.addContact(newContact)
     .subscribe(contact => {
      this.contacts.push(contact);
      this.contactService.getContact()
      .subscribe(contacts=>this.contacts = contacts);
     })
     console.log("ContactsComponent\n First: "+ newContact.fname + "\nLast:" + newContact.lname);
  }


   deleteContact(id:any)
   {
    var contacts = this.contacts;
    this.contactService.deleteContact(id)
      .subscribe(data =>{
        if(data.n==1){
          for(var i=0;i<contacts.length; i++ ){
            if(contacts[i]._id == id){
              contacts.splice(i,1);
            }
          }
        }
      })
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contactService.getContact()
        .subscribe(contacts => 
          this.contacts = contacts );
  }

}
```

`

`contact.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Contact } from './contact';
import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //retrive contact service 
  getContact()
  {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/contacts')
    .pipe( map( (res:any) => res.json() ) );
  }

  //add contact
    addContact(newContact: any) 
    {
      console.log("ContactsComponent\n First: "+ newContact.fname + "\nLast:" + newContact.lname);
      console.log('Inside addContact in Service.ts');
      var headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.append('Content-Type','application-json');
      return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/contact', newContact,{headers:headers})
      .pipe( map( (res :any ) =>res.json() ) );
    }

    //delete contact 
    deleteContact(id: any)
    {
      return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/contact/'+id)
      .pipe( map( (res :any ) =>res.json() ) );
    }
     
}
```

`

The db module, contact.js file
`

```
const ContactSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    fname:{
            type:String,
            required  : true
    },
    lname:{
        type:String,
        required  : true
    },
    phno:{
        type:String,
        required  : true
    }
});

const Contact = module.exports = mongoose.model('Contact',ContactSchema);
```

`

The app module ts file also has the HttpClient modules imported and added to Ngdeclarations.

Im not able to understand why its working in postman and not here, the getContact in services has to be invoked to display the exisitng contacts from db but it isnt working for some reason. I'm supposed to render the existing contacts and also add new contacts.

Comment: Can you see this request in the network tab of your browser? Can you specify if there is an error invoked or something just isn't shown? You should try to identify the problem in detail, e.g. is it because of the HTTP requests or is it a rendering issue?

Comment: There's no error displayed, the existing contact details from the db isn't shown, so Im guessing its the rendering issue, because if it's HTTP request issue then the postman should display error while adding new contact through that which it doesn't.